# How to limit number of lines in Textarea (Redactor)?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, redactor

I am currently having difficulty getting the Enter key to stop creating new lines in my textarea after the maximum number of rows has been reached. The number of rows are passed as a parameter in the component that I have made. My textarea is a Redactor editor and the new lines are separated by linebreaks.

I have a computed observable that determines the number of rows based on the number of linebreaks in the text and it is returning the correct value:

```
self.numberOfRows = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.value().split(/<br>/).length;
    }, this);
```

In my Redactor settings I have a keydownCallback function that compares the number of rows to the maximum number of rows and should prevent the enter key from creating a new row when the max is reached or exceeded:

```
keydownCallback: function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode > 48 || e.keyCode === 32) {
                if (self.remainingCharacters() <= 0) {                    
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            } else if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                if (self.maxRows != null) {
                    if (self.numberOfRows() >= self.maxRows) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

The first part of the callback function limits the number of characters and is working properly, however the enter key still creates new lines. I have also tried "return false;" instead of preventDefault and I've also tried stopPropagation before preventDefault, but no luck. I am not concerned about users pasting values into the textarea, nor am I concerned about word wrap. Suggestions?

Separated callbacks:

```
        enterCallback: function(e) {
            if (self.maxRows != null) {
                if (self.numberOfRows() >= self.maxRows) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        },
        keydownCallback: function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode > 48 || e.keyCode === 32) {
                if (self.remainingCharacters() <= 0) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            }
        },
```

Comment: Separated into separate callbacks, using enter call back now and still enters new line when max row reached or exceeded. The if statement in the enter callback gets executed correctly. I was able to display a message in the console when I hit the enter key and had reached max rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Had a chance to play around with Redactor and noticed that when I press return, no `<br>` are inserted and instead, new `<p>` tags are created. An empty paragraph would contain `<p><br></p>`. So the actual textarea value is something like:

```
<h2>Foo</h2>
<p>Bar
</p>
<p>Buz
</p>
```

I put together a minimal proof of concept of how this might be handled

```
$('#content').redactor({
    focus: true,
    enterCallback: function(e)
    {
        var lines = this.code.get().split(/\r?\n/g).length;
        console.log(this.code.get(), lines);
        if (lines > 3) { // self.numberOfRows()
            return false;
        }
    },
    keydownCallback: function(e)
    {
        //
    }
});
```

I'm not sure though if splitting by new line is more reliable than splitting by closing tags like `this.code.get().split(/<\/(p|h[1-6])>/)`.

I would update the regex inside the `self.numberOfRows` function to either split by new lines or closing tags

---

ORIGINAL ANSWER

Have you checked their [docs](https://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/callbacks/keypress)?
There seem to be 2 separate callbacks for [`enter`](https://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/callbacks/keypress/#callback-enter) and [`keyup`](https://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/callbacks/keypress/#callback-keyup):

> You can return false in this callback to prevent Redactor from
>   handling Enter/Return key inputs. It allows you to develop custom
>   handlers for this event.

```
$('#redactor').redactor({
    callbacks: {
        enter: function(e)
        {
            console.log(this.code.get());
            return false;
        }
    }   
});
```

Also if you look at their [Limiter plugin](https://imperavi.com/redactor/plugins/limiter/plugin), it just returns false:

```
if (count >= this.opts.limiter)
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this and still seem to be having the same behavior as my original code I posted. I posted edited callbacks to reflect your answer.

Comment: I had linebreaks set to true which inserts <br> whenever the user presses enter rather than using paragraphs tags. I took that out and am now splitting by closing the tags. It is working better. The only problem left now is the user can enter multiple empty rows before typing any text, then go back and fill them after. It stops entering new rows when the max is reached but if they entered more than the max before they started typing they can work around it.